# There's something i don't get about $http service in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

My code is not very simple, cause i had to share some properties between controllers but the problem doesn't lay there. I'm trying to add some ajax call (to exercise like all the other stuff) and i'm getting an empty array in the select option in the html layout where it should get the content of the json and fill the selection menù as result.

Here is my javascript:

```
angular.module('greetings', [])
.service("Addcontent", function($http){
     this.name = "Nome";
     this.familyName = "Cognome";
     me = this;
     me.tipi= [];
     this.ajaxCall = $http.get("http://localhost:8090/my-site/data.json").success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        me.tipi = data;
        console.log(me.tipi);
     }).error(function(){
         console.log("error");
     });
     this.selectedOption = this.tipi[0];
})
.controller('GreetingsController', function($http, Addcontent) {
  this.name = Addcontent.name;
  this.familyName = Addcontent.familyName;
  this.tipi = Addcontent.tipi;
  this.selectedOption = Addcontent.selectedOption;
}).controller("addContentController", function($scope, $window, $http, Addcontent){
      this.name = Addcontent.name;
      this.familyName = Addcontent.familyName;
      this.tipi = Addcontent.tipi;
      this.selectedOption = Addcontent.selectedOption;
      this.greet = function greet() {
          this.name = $scope.$parent.greeting.name
          this.familyName = $scope.$parent.greeting.familyName
          this.selectedOption = $scope.$parent.greeting.selectedOption
  };
});
```

And here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="greetings.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Greetings</h1>
<div ng-app="greetings" ng-controller="GreetingsController as greeting">
  <b>Greetings:</b>
  <div>
    Name: <input type="text" min="0" ng-model="greeting.name" required >
  </div>
  <div>
    FamilyName: <input type="text" ng-model="greeting.familyName" required >
    <select 
    data-ng-options="c for c in greeting.tipi" data-ng-model="greeting.selectedOption">
      <!--<option ng-repeat="c in greeting.tipi">{{c}}</option>-->
    </select>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <span>
  {{greeting.selectedOption}} {{greeting.name}} {{greeting.familyName}}
  </span>
  <div>
    <b>Greeting:</b>
    <span ng-controller="addContentController as addcontentCtrl">
      {{addcontentCtrl.selectedOption}} {{addcontentCtrl.name}} {{addcontentCtrl.familyName}}
      <!--<form ng-submit="greeting.update(greeting.selectedOption)">
      <input type="submit" value="Greeting">
      </form>-->
      <button class="btn" ng-click="addcontentCtrl.greet(addcontentCtrl.selectedOption)">Greet</button>
      <br/>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

the json to be used is:

```
[{"Hello":"1"},
 {"Good Morning":"2"}, 
 {"Good Afternoon":"3"}, 
 {"Good evening":"4"}]
```

Any idea of why the select menu ends up empty (both the console.logs activated give the right result so it should definetly work?

Comment: Are you serving the website from the same port as the api endpoint (`http://localhost:8090`)?

Comment: of course, the ajax call doesn't trow error so it is right as far as i know.

Comment: I've checked to be sure ;)

Comment: That's good. And the `console.log` prints out the result from the server?

Comment: yes it does indeed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your service and use a promise to get the list of options.

Service:

```
.service("Addcontent", function($http, $q){
     this.name = "Nome";
     this.familyName = "Cognome";
     me = this;
     me.tipi= null;
     this.getTipi = function() {
         var deferred = $q.defer();
         if( me.tipi ) {
             deferred.resolve( {options: me.tipi, selectedOption: me.selectedOption} );
         } else {
             $http.get("http://localhost:8090/my-site/data.json").success(function(data) {
                 console.log(data);
                 me.tipi = data;
                 me.selectedOption = me.tipi[0];
                 console.log(me.tipi);
                 deferred.resolve( {options: me.tipi, selectedOption: me.selectedOption} );
             }).error(function(){
                 console.log("error");
             });
         }
         return deferred.promise;
     };
});
```

And in your controller, get the results from the service:

```
var ctrl = this;
Addcontent.getTipi().then(function(data) {
    ctrl.tipi = data.options;
    ctrl.selectedOption = data.selectedOption;
});
```

I think that your `ngOptions` should be (But i'm not completely sure - I'll check):

```
ng-options="value as key for (key , value) in greeting.tipi"
```

Comment: Did you injected `$q` into the dependencies of the service?

Comment: Seems like if data was empty... maybe not receiving data from server?

Comment: Ok, i've taken away the if statement and now everything works fine. You're code is up. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that the `data-ng-options="c for c in greeting.tipi"` the c you are getting from your array is an object instead of a value that can be displayed.

Check [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) for details on ng-options. I think this example may fit your case `<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>`.

Comment: I'd have to change the json then?

Comment: Yes that would imply using a json object like `{ key: "Hello", value: "1" }` for example as part of the array, so the array would consist only of such objects.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your tipi after the ajax call
In your service

```
 this.ajaxCall = function(){
    return $http.get("http://localhost:8090/my-site/data.json").success(function(data) {
           return data;
         }).error(function(){
             console.log("error");
         });
        }
```

Then in your controller

```
Addcontent.ajaxCall().then(function(tipi){
        this.tipi=tipi;
       });
```